# How to use both form and HTTP basic authentication on ALL requests?

Tags: java, authentication, spring-security

My problem is to handle all requests firstly with basic authentication and then with custom form-login authentication.

I came from this
[Handling both form and HTTP basic authentication with different sources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9302795/handling-both-form-and-http-basic-authentication-with-different-sources)

But I want to use double authentication on ALL requests

So I want to achieve something like this:

```
<http>
    <intercept-url pattern="/**"  access="isAuthenticated()"/>
<http-basic />

    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
<form-login 
        login-page="/login" 
        default-target-url="/welcome" 
        authentication-failure-url="/login?error" 
        username-parameter="username"
        password-parameter="password" />
</http>
```

But I don't know is there any chance to do like this.

Thank you.

Comment: Possible, but I would advice against it. However, what problem did you meet?

Comment: I know that it sounds very strange, but my employer wants some double authorisation so user couldn't see our login form if he didn't pass first authorisation. It is closed system.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the question. Requiring successful Basic auth to use the login form? That makes no sense.

Comment: Yes, that's right, this makes no sense. But it is very complicated situation and I need to do basic + form authentication. So every request would pass firstly basic then form-login auth. If you can advise me how to achieve it, that would be great, because every example I found describes how to use or basic or form-login auth, but not both for all requests.